# Filtering rows in oracle based upon number of distinct values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have a table in oracle:

```
+ -----+----------+----------+-----------+
| ACC  | TYPE     | BILL_NUM | TYPE_COST |
+ -----+----------+----------+-----------+
| ACC1 | VOICE    |        1 |        10 |
| ACC1 | MMS      |        1 |         5 |
| ACC1 | VOICE    |        2 |        20 |
| ACC1 | MMS      |        2 |        15 |
| ACC1 | VOICE    |        3 |        30 |
| ACC2 | VOICE    |        1 |         3 |
| ACC2 | MMS      |        1 |         4 |
| ACC2 | MMS      |        2 |        14 |
| ACC2 | MMS      |        3 |        24 |
| ACC2 | MMS      |        4 |        34 |
+ -----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

You could see that for an account there are multiple bills and here account ACC1 has 3 bills(latest being 3) and ACC2 has 4 bills(latest being 4). I want to filter out the rows and need to see only latest 2 bills for each account. I will have account as input  in this case. I have written a query and its working:

```
with 
acclist as (
select * from (
select distinct acc,bill_num from  testdata where acc='ACC1' order by bill_num desc )
where rownum<=2
)
select * from testdata td,acclist al where td.bill_num=al.bill_num and td.acc=al.acc
```

But I believe there is a better way for doing the same.Can anybody provide me a better solution?
Below is the reference table creation:

```
create table TestData
(
ACC VARCHAR(9),
TYPE VARCHAR(20),
BILL_NUM NUMBER(9),
TYPE_COST NUMBER(9)
);

insert into testdata (ACC, TYPE, BILL_NUM, TYPE_COST)
values ('ACC1', 'VOICE', 1, 10);
insert into testdata (ACC, TYPE, BILL_NUM, TYPE_COST)
values ('ACC1', 'MMS', 1, 5);

insert into testdata (ACC, TYPE, BILL_NUM, TYPE_COST)
values ('ACC1', 'VOICE', 2, 20);
insert into testdata (ACC, TYPE, BILL_NUM, TYPE_COST)
values ('ACC1', 'MMS', 2, 15);

insert into testdata (ACC, TYPE, BILL_NUM, TYPE_COST)
values ('ACC1', 'VOICE', 3, 30);

insert into testdata (ACC, TYPE, BILL_NUM, TYPE_COST)
values ('ACC2', 'VOICE',1, 3);
insert into testdata (ACC, TYPE, BILL_NUM, TYPE_COST)
values ('ACC2', 'MMS', 1, 4);

insert into testdata (ACC, TYPE, BILL_NUM, TYPE_COST)
values ('ACC2', 'MMS', 2, 14);

insert into testdata (ACC, TYPE, BILL_NUM, TYPE_COST)
values ('ACC2', 'MMS', 3, 24);

insert into testdata (ACC, TYPE, BILL_NUM, TYPE_COST)
values ('ACC2', 'MMS', 4, 34);
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to filter out the rows and need to see only latest 2 bills for each account

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (  
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by acc order by bill_num desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 2
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6898db059074ccfc53318168b0494684)**:

```
ACC  | TYPE  | BILL_NUM | TYPE_COST
:--- | :---- | -------: | --------:
ACC1 | VOICE |        3 |        30
ACC1 | VOICE |        2 |        20
ACC2 | MMS   |        4 |        34
ACC2 | MMS   |        3 |        24
```

**Edit**

If you want to allow ties (which means that you *could* get more than two record per account in the resultset), you can use `dense_rank()` instead:

```
select *
from (  
    select t.*, dense_rank() over(partition by acc order by bill_num desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 2
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=29eb67d8afa503ab8dfb88b4a97ed537)**:

```
ACC  | TYPE  | BILL_NUM | TYPE_COST
:--- | :---- | -------: | --------:
ACC1 | VOICE |        3 |        30
ACC1 | VOICE |        2 |        20
ACC1 | MMS   |        2 |        15
ACC2 | MMS   |        4 |        34
ACC2 | MMS   |        3 |        24
```

Comment: It some how filtering out 1 valid row for ACC1

Comment: @Vijay: this query gives you the two latest records for each `acc`, `bill_num` -wise

Comment: There is one more row with same bill num for ACC1 with type as MMS. You can check output of query I mentioned where you can find the valid rows.

Comment: Use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` to get all rows for the two bills per account.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: thanks, I think that's what OP actually wants, given the above comments. I edited my answer.